# AZ cli error handling from powershell and github actions not failing

Tags: azure, powershell, error-handling

I have got a psh script which gets called from github actions, during my test I can see that the script fails as the key vault requested already exists, however I would like the github action to actually fail and not give the impression that it successfully executed.

```
param
(
  [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $resourceGroupName,
  [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $keyVaultname
)
$accessPoliciesConfig = '[{"objectId":"xxxxxxxx","certificatesPermissions":["all"], "keysPermissions":["all"], "secretsPermissions":["all"], "storagePermissions":["all"]}, {"objectId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx", "certificatesPermissions":["all"], "keysPermissions":["all"], "secretsPermissions":["all"], "storagePermissions":["all"]}]'.Replace(' ','') | ConvertTo-Json


# $users = '[{"type":"ServicePrincipal","id":"xxxx","roleid":"21090545-7ca7-4776-b22c-e363652d74d2"}]'.Replace(' ','') | ConvertTo-Json
$users = '[]'.Replace(' ','') | ConvertTo-Json

try{
    $kvName = "$keyVaultPrefix-$application-$audience-$environment"
    # $keyVaultExist = az keyvault show --name $kvName
    if(!$keyVaultExist){

    az deployment group create --resource-group $resourceGroupName --template-file '.\iac\create_kv.bicep' --parameters accessPoliciesConfig=$accessPoliciesConfig users=$users keyVault_name=$keyVaultname

}
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $Error
    throw
    return 1
}
```

Comment: In Windows PowerShell and in PowerShell (Core) up to v7.3.x _invariably_ and in v7.4+ _by default_, calls to external programs do _not_ cause PowerShell errors that you can catch with `try { ... } catch { ... }` (there are selective, _accidental_ exceptions in Windows PowerShell that cannot be relied upon). To detect an external program's failure, check if its process exit code, reflected in the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable, is _non-zero_ and take explicit action based on that.
See the linked duplicate for details.